# LiveData Observer still observing when going back to the fragment

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

So I have this code that when i press a button

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
    val user = UserLogin(etUsername.text.toString(), etPassword.text.toString())
    viewModel.login(user)
}
```

I will observe this

```
fun login(user: UserLogin) {
    loginGateway.loginBuyer(user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe { _loginState.postValue(LoginLoading) }
            .subscribe({
                if(it.data != null)
                    _loginState.postValue(LoginSuccess(it.data))
                else
                    _loginState.postValue(LoginFailed(it.message))
            }, {
                _loginState.postValue(LoginError(it.localizedMessage))
            })
            .addTo(disposable)
}
```

and here is the observer

```
        viewModel.loginState.observe(this, Observer {it ->
        when (it) {
            LoginLoading -> {
                dialog.show()
            }

            is LoginSuccess -> {
                dialog.dismiss()
                if (cbRemember.isChecked)
                    viewModel.saveUsername(etUsername.text!!.toString())
                viewModel.saveFirstname(it.user.firstName)
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.toMain)
            }

            is LoginFailed -> {
                dialog.dismiss()
                showErrorDialog(this.context!!, "Login Failed", it.message)
            }

            is LoginError -> {
                dialog.dismiss()
                showErrorDialog(this.context!!, "Login Error", it.message)
            }

        }
   })
```

---

So this is the problem when I have failed a login so it will show a dialog and when dismissed and when I go to register page and go back to login the same dialog still appears.

I tried doing like putting `removeObservers(this)` on the onPause() and onDestroy() but its still the same. I'm not quite sure if the problem lies with the fragment lifecycle if not please help me understand whats happening. I'm new with kotlin and mvvm so please. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `viewModel.loginState` is like it's named a state which lives within the `viewModel`. When you navigate to the navigation, the observation will be suspended, but also restarted after you navigate back. Since you don't change the state itself, maybe only dismiss the dialog, you'll end up with the same screen as before.

So just update the state to a more relevant value when you dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for this workaround! This worked but is this the best practice for this type of problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        viewModel.isDialogOpen.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { isDialogOpen ->
            if (!isDialogOpen) {
                this@Fragment.closeAllBaseDialogFragments()
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a set btn, When the set btn is clicked, I set this variable isDialogOpen to false ,sometimes ,obsever is not working  and it is not coming into if condition .